# The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations

Tags: linq, visual-studio, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have two SQL tables:

```
    class DiaryItem
    {
        private System.Guid Id;

        private string Name;
    }

    class DiaryActivityItem
    {
        private System.Guid Id;

        private int Minutes;
    }
```

DiaryActivityItem.Id is a foreign key to DiaryItem.Id.

And I get this error message now:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'MyProject.Models.DiaryActivityItem' and
>   'MyProject.Models.DiaryItem'. The principal end of this association
>   must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API
>   or data annotations.

Now, I found out that I must write `[ForeignKey("Id")]` before `DiaryActivityItem.Id` to fix this, but my problem is that my classes are autogenerated. I've got this Model `DataClasses.dbml`l; when double-clicking on it, I get a visual model designer and every change I make (and subsequently save) causes the whole file will be rewritten, so manually adding this ForeignKey Annotation doesn't work.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your code as follow:

```
public  class DiaryItem
{
    public System.Guid DiaryItemId;

    public string Name;

    [ForeignKey("DiaryActivityItem")] 
    public System.Guid DiaryActivityItemId;

    public DiaryActivityItem DiaryActivityItem;
}

public  class DiaryActivityItem
{
    public System.Guid DiaryActivityItemId;

    public int Minutes;
}
```